# How to filter content in json swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2

I have a side menu with various categories such as: "all posts, international, national etc" in my app. Now I'm receiving data from an API and parsing it using JSON. This data is being stored in `NSDictionary`.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

class Member
{
    let imageName: NSData!
    let name: String?
    let about: String?
    let tag : String?

    init(dictionary:NSDictionary)
    {
        let url = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
        let imgdata = NSURL(string: url!)
        imageName = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgdata!)
        name = dictionary["title"] as? String
        tag = dictionary["TAG"] as? String
        // fixup the about text to add newlines
        let unescapedAbout = dictionary["postBody"] as? String
        about = unescapedAbout?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString:"\n", options:[], range:nil)
    }

    class func loadMembersFromFile(path: NSURL) -> [Member]
    {
        var members:[Member] = []
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: path),
        //  if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[]),
            json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)as? NSDictionary,
            team = json["items"] as? [NSDictionary]{
                for memberDictionary in team {
                    let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
                    members.append(member)
                }
        }
        return members
    }
}
```

Now the JSON file contains a field as TAG="international", TAG="national" and so on.

I want to filter this JSON data according to the above tag and load only the data belonging to the corresponding side menu entry in my table view.

Comment: Before `members.append(member)` check the `member.tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check the value of the TAG before appending your 'new' member to the array

```
for memberDictionary in team {
    let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
    guard let tag = member.tag as? String else {
        continue 
    }
    if tag == theTag {  // Add a parameter 'theTag' (String) to your method
        members.append(member)
    }
}
```